# Add image to drawable for Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-notifications, android-bitmap, android-glide

I'm currently setting up notifications for my app.

I want to set a large icon on each notification to give the user more visual information.

According to the docs, this is how to set a large icon on the notification:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.notification_icon);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("Title")
    .setContentText("Message")
    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

However, this is a problem for me because my drawable is simply a shape (rectangle), and I need to do the following changes to the drawable before setting it as the notification icon:

1. Change the background color of the drawable to `user.getColor()` (returns a HEX, e.g. #000000).
2. Add an image on top of the drawable given a URL (I'm using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) if that helps).

In the end, it should look something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXsWB.png

Here is my drawable, `notification_icon.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <size
        android:width="64dp"
        android:height="64dp" />

    <corners
        android:radius="4dp" />

    <padding
        android:left="8dp"
        android:top="8dp"
        android:right="8dp"
        android:bottom="8dp" />

</shape>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: See this answer :stackoverflow.com/questions/44219271/is-there-a-simple-way-to-show-an-image-with-a-frame-with-glide/44219686#44219686

Comment: read `android.graphics.Canvas` documentation on how to draw various things on the canvas